# Python And Or statements acting ..weird

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators, demorgans-law

I have this simple line of code:

```
i = " "

if i != "" or i != " ":
    print("Something")
```

This should be simple, if i is not empty `""` OR it's not a space `" "`, but it is, print Something. Now, why I see Something printed if one of those 2 conditions is `False`?

Comment: Are you asking why only one condition must be true when you use OR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),

```
"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

also,

"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".
```

In your case, as per the first statement, you have effectively written

```
if not (i == "" and i == " "):
```

which is not possible to occur. So whatever may be the input, `(i == "" and i == " ")` will always return `False` and negating it will give `True` always.

---

Instead, you should have written it like this

```
if i != "" and i != " ":
```

or as per the quoted second statement from the De Morgan's law,

```
if not (i == "" or i == " "):
```

Comment: Or you skip the explicit `and`/`or` and go with `if i not in ('', ' '):`

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if i != "" or i != " ":
```

will always be true.  You probably want `and` instead of `or`...

Answer (score 0):

I will explain how `or` works.
If checks the first condition and if it is true it does not even check for the second condition.
If the first condition is false only then it checks for second condition and if it is true the whole thing becomes true.
Because

```
A B Result  
0 0   0  
0 1   1  
1 0   1  
1 1   1
```

So If you want to satisfy both condition of not empty and space use `and`

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement will always happen, because your logic statement is always going to be True.
`if A or B:`
will be True if either A is True OR B is True OR both are True. Because of the way you've written the statement, one of the two will always be True. More precisely, with your statement as written, the if statement correlates to `if True or False:` which simplifies to `if True:`. 
It seems that you want an `and` statement instead of an `or`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = " "
```

you have the condition as

```
if i != "" or i != " ":
```

here `i != ""` will evaluate to `True` and `i != " "` will evaluate to `False`

so you will have `True or False` = `True`

you can refer this truth table for `OR` [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

```
True  or False = True
False or True  = True
True  or True  = True
False or False = False
```