# Why is there error with " != " not equal in my code while comparing strings in python?

Tags: python

I got error while comparing the strings. What is the error here?

I was unable to find the problem and its solution.

My code is this:

```
  def login():
      user_name=input("Enter the user name:")
      password=input("Enter the password:")
      confirm=input("Confirm the above information is correct (y/n):")
      if confirm != 'y' or confirm != 'Y':
          print("Is not true!")
          login()
      return user_name,password
```

I am getting this instead of returning the values?

```
Enter the user name:>? vsdfv
Enter the password:>? cvsdf
Confirm the above information is correct (y/n):>? y
y
Is not true!
Enter the user name:
```

Comment: You should be using `and`, not `or`.

Comment: or `if not confirm in ['y', 'Y']` or `if confirm.upper() != 'Y'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python And Or statements acting ..weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496768/python-and-or-statements-acting-weird)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `or`, one of the conditions will always be `true`. Use `and` instead

```
if confirm != 'y' and confirm != 'Y':
    print("Is not true!")
```

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws → `not(a or b) = not(a) and not(b)`

Comment: Oh its a blunder. Thank you so much.

Comment: Or even better: `if confirm not in ['y', 'Y']:`

Comment: @Aryerez this will check all the options in the list, my solution might finish after one check, in case `confirm` is `'y'` (not a big issue with two options, but still).

Comment: @Guy the time is takes to write all the `and`s is a few magnidutes greater than the time it takes python to make a simple comparison, and the code would be much easier to maintain

Answer (score -1):

`or` in basically every programming language is not the same as "or" in natural language. In computer science it means that the overall expression is true, if at least one of both sub-expressions evaluates to true. Therefore, your boolean expression always yields true, because if the first expression evaluates to true, the second will evaluate to false and the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

You used `or` and you entered `y`. Since one of the conditions is true
(`confirm != 'Y'`), it will evaluate to true.
Use `and` instead.